# Why does this bash script work even with the typo

Tags: bash, shell

So I have this bash script to find the Fibonacci sequence for n terms. Its definitely not great code, but I notices that it still works with a typo

```
read -p "Enter which term of fibo seq to find: " n

table=(1 1)

for i in $(seq 0 $(($n - 1)) )
do
    if [[ -z ${table[$i]} ]]; then
        a1=$(( $i - 1 ))
        a2=$(( $I - 2 ))
        val=$(( ${table[$a1]} + ${table[$a2]} ))

        table+=($val)
    fi
done

echo ${table[@]}
```

inside the if statement evaluating the expression for a2, there is a capital 'I' instead of 'i'. My understanding is that shellscript is case sensitive but I'm new to it. So can anyone explain why this works?

Comment: I tried to echo $I but got nothing and now I'm more confused. Please help.

Comment: as an FYI to everyone, shellcheck.net didn't flag the `$I` as an empty variable. It did of course mention that `$`s isn't needed inside of `$(( ...))` exprressions and also flagged all unquoted variables in use. Good luck too all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a2` will always be -2. [Starting with bash 4.2](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/36f2c40/CHANGES#L3034-L3035), you can index into an array using negative indices, much like in Python. So with or without the typo, you are always accessing the second last element in the array.

Comment: This means you could remove `a1` and `a2`, and use use `val=$(( ${table[-1]} + ${table[-2]} ))`

Answer (score 1):

The statement `a2=$(( $I - 2 ))` where `$I` is not declared is equal to `a2=$(( - 2 ))` which means `a2` will always be equal to `-2`.

Comment: To be precise, a null or unset variable is evaluated as `0` in an arithmetic context, see [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic).